# How to rename huge amount of files in Hadoop/Spark?

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, bigdata, apache-spark

I have an input folder that contains +100,000 files.

I would like to do a batch operation on them, i.e. rename all of them in a certain way, or move them to a new path based on information in each file's name.

I would like to use Spark to do that, but unfortunately when I tried the following piece of code:

```
 final org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem ghfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI(args[0]), new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration());
        org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus[] paths = ghfs.listStatus(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(args[0]));
        List<String> pathsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FileStatus path : paths) {
            pathsList.add(path.getPath().toString());
        }
        JavaRDD<String> rddPaths = sc.parallelize(pathsList);

        rddPaths.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String path) throws Exception {
                Path origPath = new Path(path);
                Path newPath = new Path(path.replace("taboola","customer"));
                ghfs.rename(origPath,newPath);
            }
        });
```

I get an error that hadoop.fs.FileSystem is not Serializable (and therefore probably cannot be used in parallel operations)

Any idea how I can workaround it or have it done another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to serialize the ghfs object.  If you use mapPartitions and recreate the ghfs object in each partition you will be able to run your code with just a couple of minor changes.

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly the direction I will take!

Answer (score 4):

You need to do `FileSystem.get` inside of the `VoidFunction` too.

The driver needs a FileSystem to get the list of files, but also each worker needs a FileSystem for the renaming. The driver cannot pass its FileSystem to the workers, because it is not Serializable. But the workers can get their own FileSystem just fine.

In the Scala API you could use `RDD.foreachPartition` to write the code in a way that you only do `FileSystem.get` once per partition, instead of once per line. It is probably available in the Java API as well.

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly the direction I will take (only I'm with Java at the moment...)

Comment: After all that arguing the OP goes and accepts a late answer that's basically a subset of your's

Comment: Bad karma for arguing too much :).

Comment: renaming part file in hdfs using spark 

    
 Hi I am Trying to rename part-*.csv files from hdfs to .csv 
 
 I tried below snippet but directory strucure not creating as per my need
 
 here is my try,

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend just renaming them like you were with the file system class in just a non map reduce context (just in the driver), it's not a big deal to rename 100k files, it's it's too slow, then you can attempt to multithread it. Just do something like

```
FileSystem fileSystem = new Path("").getFileSystem(new Configuration());
File [] files =  FileUtil.listFiles(directory)
for (File file : files) {
    fileSystem.rename(new Path(file.getAbsolutePath()),new Path("renamed"));
}
```

Btw the error that you're getting in spark is because spark requires objects it uses to implement Serializable, which FileSystem does not.

---

I can't confirm this but it would seem that every rename in HDFS would involve the NameNode since it tracks the full directory structure and node location of files ([confirmation link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NameNode)), meaning it can't be done efficiently in parallel. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935977/about-hadoop-hdfs-filesystem-rename) renaming is a metadata only operation so it should be very fast run serially.

Comment: The question is not about modifying anything inside the RDD. It is about running some operation for each line of the RDD in a distributed way. Maybe you have the patience to run the rename from one machine, but it's an absolutely valid use of Spark to distribute this work to many machines.

Comment: @DanielDarabos ok you're right that the immutability of RDD's has nothing to do with this issue deleted from answer. But I still think spark is overkill for renaming some files

Comment: @DanielDarabos also don't quote me on this but it's certainly possible that renaming files in the same directory can't be done in parallel on HDFS and thus your solution will have issues with mappers being blocked

Comment: Could be! It would be great if OP were to report back on the relative speeds of the two approaches.

Comment: @DanielDarabos so I can't confirm it because hdfs's source has way too many places this could be coming from, but I believe that every rename operation involves the name node (added to answer). Also the downvote, is that you, unless you still think there is something wrong with my answer I would appreciate you removing it

Comment: The question is about how to do something _with_ Spark. Your answer is about how to do it _without_ Spark. Hence my downvote. I don't recall renaming, but I remember using MR for deleting a ton of files. It is a good use of a distributed system. Not all distributed filesystems are crippled in the way you suggest HDFS is.

Comment: @DanielDarabos IDK if the OP is required to use spark, as for the down vote read [when to down vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), while I'm not particularly proud of this answer, I do believe I am correct in saying spark is not the correct approach for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56971/discussion-between-aaronman-and-daniel-darabos).

Comment: Not only does this not answer the question, this is wrong: "if it's too slow, then you can attempt to multithread it".  I do not expect that the commenter actually tried this.  In my experience, HDFS interfaces tend to serialize requests across multiple threads and very little gain is realized.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem when my hdfs archive directory reached max item limit

```
Request error: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.FSLimitException$MaxDirectoryItemsExceededException
The directory item limit of /my/archive is exceeded: limit=1048576 items=1048576
```

I decided to move all items from prev year (2015) to separate subfolder.
Here's pure shell solution

```
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xmx4096m"
hdfs dfs -ls /my/archive \
    | grep 2015- \
    | awk '{print $8}' \
    | gnu-parallel -X -s 131000 hdfs dfs -mv {} /my/archive/2015
```

Remarks:

1. client opts override is needed by `hdfs dfs -ls` because of large amount of files. See [here](https://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/hadoop-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error/) for more details.
2. `hdfs dfs` client has limit for argument list lenght: about `131000` (`2^17`) chars.
3. It took few minutes to move 420k files.