# Rename directory in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, command, hdfs

I need to rename a directory in hdfs. What is the command for that ?

```
hadoop fs -mv <src> <dest>
```

The above command moves the src folder into dest folder. Instead of, I want the `src` folder to be renamed as `dest`.

Answer (score 25):

Rename is not in hadoop, but you can move,
**hadoop fs -mv oldname newname**

Comment: And is as cheap as a simple rename, [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935977/about-hadoop-hdfs-filesystem-rename?rq=1)

Answer (score 12):

I think you are missing the point about `mv` command(linux/hdfs).

When the destination already exists, if it's a file, an error message `mv: 'dest': File exists`.
In case of directory, the source will go inside it. So the command is working acceptably, just try it with a non-existent dest.

Now to resolve this, you can make use of hadoop's `test` command along with short circuit `OR` of linux.

```
hadoop fs -test -e dest || hadoop fs -mv src dest
```

If the directory doesn't exist, invoke `mv`. You can even go further with the following:

```
hadoop fs -rmr dest  
hadoop fs -mv src dest
```

This one deletes the dest dir first, then performs the move action. if this is not your intention, use the previous solution.

Comment: Good point : In case of directory, the source will go inside it. I didnt know this before

Comment: This isnt accurate for me. I get the error; `mv: /path/project-latest : No such file or directory` when calling `hdfs dfs -mv /path/project-0.1/ /path/project-latest/`.

Comment: just found a key poing when doing a move for purpose of rename, do not put trailing slashes or it will error. Instead, do `hdfs dfs -mv /path/project-0.1/ /path/project-latest`

Answer (score 8):

You can rename the folder in HDFS environment by using mv command

```
hadoop fs -mv 'Old folder name with path' ' new folder name with path'
```

Example: I have folder in HDFS at location `/test/abc` and I want to rename it to `PQR`

```
hadoop fs -mv '/test/abc' '/test/PQR';
```

Results:

[image: Rename folder in HDFS]