# HDFS command to replace a character

Tags: hadoop, command, hdfs, command-line-interface

I have a folder name in HDFS `Data#` and I wanted replace it `Data=`

Is there a way to do it hdfs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename directory in hdfs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286946/rename-directory-in-hdfs)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Data#` is just short for the HDFS path of the folders a simple solution to achieve this would be to simply move your folder

`hadoop fs -mv Data# Data=`

If `Data#` is only the folder name you will need the full HDFS path as well and the command becomes something like:

`hadoop fs -mv full/path/to/Data# full/path/to/Data=`

where you will need to change `full/path/to` to the actual HDFS path.